# Simplify or reduce if statement

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to reduce the number of If by replacing them by a switch or a function is it possible??
since my code is too long I think a function can do the job better than a repetitive if or else and It will also be more understandable.

```
 double a = text.charAt(39), b= text.charAt(40), c= text.charAt(41), d= text.charAt(42) ;
       Collection<Double> list=new ArrayList<Double>();
        list.add(a);
        list.add(b);
        list.add(c);
        list.add(d);
        if ( a>=15||b>=15||c>=15||d>=15) {
            if (  Collections.max(list) == a) {
                Defauts_detecteur.setText("Défauts récurrents constatés sur le détecteur 1");
            }
            else if ( Collections.max(list) == b)
            {
                Defauts_detecteur.setText("Défauts récurrents constatés sur le détecteur 2");
            }
            else if ( Collections.max(list) == c )
            {
                Defauts_detecteur.setText("Défauts récurrents constatés sur le détecteur 3");
            }
            else
            {
                Defauts_detecteur.setText("Défauts récurrents constatés sur le détecteur 4");
            }

            Conseil_detecteur.setText("--> Par mesure de sécurité, nous vous conseillons vivement de vérifier que le détecteur est bien collé au produit à sécuriser.\nPour une adhésion optimale, remplacez l’adhésif.\nVérifiez que le détecteur est bien connecté à la centrale et qu’il est en bon état.");

        }
        else {
            Conseil_detecteur.setText("--> Des alarmes régulières ? Envie d'en savoir plus ?\nContactez notre hotliner au 02 37 33 69 66 qui vous guidera dans leurs résolutions.");
            Defauts_detecteur.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Comment: Is your inner `else` really an else or should that be `max(list) == d` too?

Comment: switch case statements allways want a number as paramater, switch(id) case 4: ...
if your if body only contains one statement you can write it WITHOUT brackets( { )

Comment: If your code is in working order, you'd be probably better off asking on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: `text.charAt()` gives you the character at this position, not a double value (measurement?). So `"abc123".charAt(0)` gives `97`, ".charAt(3)` gives `49`. Is that intended?

Comment: Also note that comparing doubles by `==` may not work.

Comment: @knittl yes it intended, I wanted to convert the char value to an int or double but i put double because the list doesnt run with int values

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't run with int values? It should work equally well for (boxed) `Character` or `Integer` values. See part of my answer about using an array instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a loop (or a stream, depending on performance requirements):

```
final double a = text.charAt(39), b = text.charAt(40), c = text.charAt(41), d = text.charAt(42) ;
final List<Double> list = Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d); // note that an array (double[]) instead of a collection would avoid boxing

final double maxValue = Collections.max(list);
if (maxValue >= 15) { // at least one value is greater than or equal to 15, no need to inspect each element individually
   for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
      if (list.get(i) == maxValue) {
        Defauts_detecteur.setText("Défauts récurrents constatés sur le détecteur " + (i+1));
        break; // stop after first matching value was found
      }
   }

   Conseil_detecteur.setText("--> Par mesure de sécurité, nous vous conseillons vivement de vérifier que le détecteur est bien collé au produit à sécuriser.\nPour une adhésion optimale, remplacez l’adhésif.\nVérifiez que le détecteur est bien connecté à la centrale et qu’il est en bon état.");
} else {
   Conseil_detecteur.setText("--> Des alarmes régulières ? Envie d'en savoir plus ?\nContactez notre hotliner au 02 37 33 69 66 qui vous guidera dans leurs résolutions.");
   Defauts_detecteur.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Note that your current code has unclear behavior if two of the values are identical and max (e.g. a=16, b=16, c=12, d=9). The output is "detector 1", but "detector 2" is also the max.

If you your list can contain multiple max values and you want to find all of them, you need to slightly alter your loop (but your existing code only found the position of "first" value).

```
final List<Integer> maxPositions = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
  if (list.get(i) == maxValue) {
    maxPositions.add(i+1);
    // don't stop, keep going
  }
}

// will print e.g. "found at positions [1, 4]
….setText("Max values found at positions " + maxPositions);
```

Comment: How can it be solved in this case  if I have two identical max values?

Comment: @Antoine I don't know. I don't know what your expectations are. Do you want to find the positions of all biggest values in your list? Or the first biggest value? Or the latest biggest value?

Comment: I want to find the position of the biggest value upper than 15, and in the case that 2 or 3 values are equal and upper than 15, i want to find them too.

Comment: You want to find the position not the value, correct?

Comment: Yes I want to find the position of max(and superior of 15) value  . and then I put the position of this value in the text below.

Comment: @Antoine I had already updated my answer before your latest comment. Can you check again?

Answer (score 0):

Functional style:

```
    HashMap<Character, Integer> values = new HashMap<>();
    values.put('a', 239);
    values.put('b', 123);
    values.put('c', 345);
    values.put('d', 555);

    Optional<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> max = values.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() > 15).max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
    max.ifPresent(characterIntegerEntry -> System.out.println(" max entry value for detector " + characterIntegerEntry.getKey() + " is" + characterIntegerEntry.getValue()));
```

will work with arbitrary amount of data.

Comment: `switch` cannot work on non-constant values.

Comment: The problem with switch here is that switch labels need to be literal/constant values. That's not the case here